# renaming a project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What is the easiest and fastest way to rename a projgect in visual studio 2005, including changing the folder name of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that:

1. Rename project within VS
2. Remove project from the solution
3. Manually rename folder
4. And finally add project back to the solution

Is the only way I know.

Answer (score 0):

Open the solution->remove the project

Opne Windows Explorer, Rename The Folder and the project

Reload the solution and add the project back in again.
Alternatively, you can open the solution file with notepad and change the project path manually

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method:

1) In windows explorer/command line, rename the project file and directory

2) Open the .SLN and search-and-replace the old project name with the new project name

That'll do ya